# .htaccess The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have unusual problem. On my local machine everything works fine. I have mod_rewite enabled on both machines. Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?s=$1 [L]
```

This code doesn't work on server. When I call address www.example.com/registration I get 404 Not Found. Do you know of any options I can enable to get this to work.

Comment: Maybe a leading slash problem. Try with this rule: `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php?s=$1 [L]`

Comment: @Luka: Make sure .htaccess is enabled on the other server.

Comment: I can assure you, it is. :/